# Carrierwave video thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, rubygems, thumbnails

I am using the carrierwave gem (http://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for ruby on rails.

How do I go about creating thumbnails for video uploads?

In my previous implementation with Paperclip, I was using FFMPEG.
How / where should this be done in Carrierwave?

There aren't too many useful resources on Google on this. Perhaps, someone with more experience can provide feedback.

Has anyone attempted to do this. Do share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it working as mentioned

It seems that the processing via ffmpeg needs to be done before model.save

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented actually on Carrierwave. So you need code it yourself by some process action in your Upload Class.

Comment: Yea how so? I have an uploader class. Where in the uploader class do I put the ffmpeg command? Second, how do I set carrierwave to recognise this thumbnail so I can do something like Video.attachment.thumb.url